# how can i call a function with javascript as soon as the input changes?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a webapplication that calculates a SHA1 hash depending on the input. However, the hash should be recalculated every time a letter or character changes in the input field. In my code the SHA1 hash is calculated once and is therefore always wrong at the beginning, because it calculates the hash value of an empty input.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <div id="box">
    </div>
</head>

<body>
    <header>

        <table>
            <td>
                <h1>Überschrift</h1>
            </td>
            <td>
        </table>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
        <main>
        </main>
    </div>

    </div>
    <form id="form" action="/cgi-bin/test.py" method="POST" onInput="Geeks()">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Passworteingabe</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Passwort:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="passwordcheck" id="passwordcheck" id="passwordcheck" "onChange=" Geeks()">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="hidden" id="myfield" name="myfield" value="">

        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </div>


    <script>
msg=document.getElementById("passwordcheck").value

function SHA1 (msg) {

 


    function rotate_left(n,s) {


        var t4 = ( n<<s ) | (n>>>(32-s));


        return t4;


    };

 


    function lsb_hex(val) {


        var str="";


        var i;


        var vh;


        var vl;

 


        for( i=0; i<=6; i+=2 ) {


            vh = (val>>>(i*4+4))&0x0f;


            vl = (val>>>(i*4))&0x0f;


            str += vh.toString(16) + vl.toString(16);


        }


        return str;


    };

 


    function cvt_hex(val) {


        var str="";


        var i;


        var v;

 


        for( i=7; i>=0; i-- ) {


            v = (val>>>(i*4))&0x0f;


            str += v.toString(16);


        }


        return str;


    };

 

 


    function Utf8Encode(string) {


        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");


        var utftext = "";

 


        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

 


            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

 


            if (c < 128) {


                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);


            }


            else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {


                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);


                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);


            }


            else {


                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);


                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);


                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);


            }

 


        }

 


        return utftext;


    };

 


    var blockstart;


    var i, j;


    var W = new Array(80);


    var H0 = 0x67452301;


    var H1 = 0xEFCDAB89;


    var H2 = 0x98BADCFE;


    var H3 = 0x10325476;


    var H4 = 0xC3D2E1F0;


    var A, B, C, D, E;


    var temp;

 


    msg = Utf8Encode(msg);

 


    var msg_len = msg.length;

 
    var word_array = new Array();


    for( i=0; i<msg_len-3; i+=4 ) {


        j = msg.charCodeAt(i)<<24 | msg.charCodeAt(i+1)<<16 |


        msg.charCodeAt(i+2)<<8 | msg.charCodeAt(i+3);


        word_array.push( j );


    }

 


    switch( msg_len % 4 ) {


        case 0:


            i = 0x080000000;


        break;


        case 1:


            i = msg.charCodeAt(msg_len-1)<<24 | 0x0800000;


        break;

 


        case 2:


            i = msg.charCodeAt(msg_len-2)<<24 | msg.charCodeAt(msg_len-1)<<16 | 0x08000;


        break;

 


        case 3:


            i = msg.charCodeAt(msg_len-3)<<24 | msg.charCodeAt(msg_len-2)<<16 | msg.charCodeAt(msg_len-1)<<8    | 0x80;


        break;


    }

 


    word_array.push( i );

 


    while( (word_array.length % 16) != 14 ) word_array.push( 0 );

 


    word_array.push( msg_len>>>29 );


    word_array.push( (msg_len<<3)&0x0ffffffff );

 

 


    for ( blockstart=0; blockstart<word_array.length; blockstart+=16 ) {

 


        for( i=0; i<16; i++ ) W[i] = word_array[blockstart+i];


        for( i=16; i<=79; i++ ) W[i] = rotate_left(W[i-3] ^ W[i-8] ^ W[i-14] ^ W[i-16], 1);

 


        A = H0;


        B = H1;


        C = H2;


        D = H3;


        E = H4;

 


        for( i= 0; i<=19; i++ ) {


            temp = (rotate_left(A,5) + ((B&C) | (~B&D)) + E + W[i] + 0x5A827999) & 0x0ffffffff;


            E = D;


            D = C;


            C = rotate_left(B,30);


            B = A;


            A = temp;


        }

 


        for( i=20; i<=39; i++ ) {


            temp = (rotate_left(A,5) + (B ^ C ^ D) + E + W[i] + 0x6ED9EBA1) & 0x0ffffffff;


            E = D;


            D = C;


            C = rotate_left(B,30);


            B = A;


            A = temp;


        }

 


        for( i=40; i<=59; i++ ) {


            temp = (rotate_left(A,5) + ((B&C) | (B&D) | (C&D)) + E + W[i] + 0x8F1BBCDC) & 0x0ffffffff;


            E = D;


            D = C;


            C = rotate_left(B,30);


            B = A;


            A = temp;


        }

 


        for( i=60; i<=79; i++ ) {


            temp = (rotate_left(A,5) + (B ^ C ^ D) + E + W[i] + 0xCA62C1D6) & 0x0ffffffff;


            E = D;


            D = C;


            C = rotate_left(B,30);


            B = A;


            A = temp;


        }

 


        H0 = (H0 + A) & 0x0ffffffff;


        H1 = (H1 + B) & 0x0ffffffff;


        H2 = (H2 + C) & 0x0ffffffff;


        H3 = (H3 + D) & 0x0ffffffff;


        H4 = (H4 + E) & 0x0ffffffff;

 


    }

 


    var temp = cvt_hex(H0) + cvt_hex(H1) + cvt_hex(H2) + cvt_hex(H3) + cvt_hex(H4);

 


    return temp.toLowerCase();

}

f1=SHA1(msg)
document.write(f1)
document.getElementById('myfield').value=SHA1(msg)


</script>

<script>
function Geeks() { 
  var y = SHA1(msg)
                var x = document.getElementById("myfield").value; 
                document.getElementById("sudo").innerHTML = 
                "Entered Text: "  + SHA1(msg); 
            } 
</script>

     <p id="sudo"></p> 

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Felix, please try to strip down your example to a minimum. I think 10-15 lines of code should be enough to show your issue.

Comment: this is not a problem regarding event something wrong inside your SHA1 returning data i reccomend you please debug that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors in the code. Below are the suggested changes to fix the issue:

1. `<input type="text" name="passwordcheck" id="passwordcheck" "onChange="Geeks()">`; there is a additional " before onChange which is not needed.
   It should be `<input type="text" name="passwordcheck" id="passwordcheck" onChange="Geeks()">`
2. You are using `onchange` listener; where as onchange event occurs when the element loses focus. Use `oninput` or `onkeyup` instead as you want the hash to update as the content of the passwordcheck box changes
3. Remove the `onInput="Geeks()"` listener from the from.
4. Pass the updated value to `SHA1()` function by using `event.target.value` instead of Global msg variable.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need any further clarifications.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Title</title>
  <div id="box">
  </div>
</head>

<body>
  <header>

    <table>
      <td>
        <h1>Überschrift</h1>
      </td>
      <td>
    </table>
  </header>
  <div id="content">
    <main>
    </main>
  </div>

  </div>
  <form id="form" action="/cgi-bin/test.py" method="POST">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Passworteingabe</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Passwort:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="passwordcheck" id="passwordcheck" oninput="Geeks(event)">

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="hidden" id="myfield" name="myfield" value="">

    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  </div>


  <script>
    msg = document.getElementById("passwordcheck").value

    function SHA1(msg) {
      function rotate_left(n, s) {
        var t4 = (n << s) | (n >>> (32 - s));
        return t4;
      };

      function lsb_hex(val) {
        var str = "";
        var i;
        var vh;
        var vl;
        for (i = 0; i <= 6; i += 2) {
          vh = (val >>> (i * 4 + 4)) & 0x0f;
          vl = (val >>> (i * 4)) & 0x0f;
          str += vh.toString(16) + vl.toString(16);
        }
        return str;
      };

      function cvt_hex(val) {
        var str = "";
        var i;
        var v;
        for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
          v = (val >>> (i * 4)) & 0x0f;
          str += v.toString(16);
        }
        return str;
      };

      function Utf8Encode(string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
        var utftext = "";
        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
          var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
          if (c < 128) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
          } else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
          } else {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
          }
        }
        return utftext;
      };
      var blockstart;
      var i, j;
      var W = new Array(80);
      var H0 = 0x67452301;
      var H1 = 0xEFCDAB89;
      var H2 = 0x98BADCFE;
      var H3 = 0x10325476;
      var H4 = 0xC3D2E1F0;
      var A, B, C, D, E;
      var temp;
      msg = Utf8Encode(msg);
      var msg_len = msg.length;
      var word_array = new Array();
      for (i = 0; i < msg_len - 3; i += 4) {
        j = msg.charCodeAt(i) << 24 | msg.charCodeAt(i + 1) << 16 |
          msg.charCodeAt(i + 2) << 8 | msg.charCodeAt(i + 3);
        word_array.push(j);
      }
      switch (msg_len % 4) {
        case 0:
          i = 0x080000000;
          break;
        case 1:
          i = msg.charCodeAt(msg_len - 1) << 24 | 0x0800000;
          break;
        case 2:
          i = msg.charCodeAt(msg_len - 2) << 24 | msg.charCodeAt(msg_len - 1) << 16 | 0x08000;
          break;
        case 3:
          i = msg.charCodeAt(msg_len - 3) << 24 | msg.charCodeAt(msg_len - 2) << 16 | msg.charCodeAt(msg_len - 1) << 8 | 0x80;
          break;
      }
      word_array.push(i);
      while ((word_array.length % 16) != 14) word_array.push(0);
      word_array.push(msg_len >>> 29);
      word_array.push((msg_len << 3) & 0x0ffffffff);
      for (blockstart = 0; blockstart < word_array.length; blockstart += 16) {
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) W[i] = word_array[blockstart + i];
        for (i = 16; i <= 79; i++) W[i] = rotate_left(W[i - 3] ^ W[i - 8] ^ W[i - 14] ^ W[i - 16], 1);
        A = H0;
        B = H1;
        C = H2;
        D = H3;
        E = H4;
        for (i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
          temp = (rotate_left(A, 5) + ((B & C) | (~B & D)) + E + W[i] + 0x5A827999) & 0x0ffffffff;
          E = D;
          D = C;
          C = rotate_left(B, 30);
          B = A;
          A = temp;
        }
        for (i = 20; i <= 39; i++) {
          temp = (rotate_left(A, 5) + (B ^ C ^ D) + E + W[i] + 0x6ED9EBA1) & 0x0ffffffff;
          E = D;
          D = C;
          C = rotate_left(B, 30);
          B = A;
          A = temp;
        }
        for (i = 40; i <= 59; i++) {
          temp = (rotate_left(A, 5) + ((B & C) | (B & D) | (C & D)) + E + W[i] + 0x8F1BBCDC) & 0x0ffffffff;
          E = D;
          D = C;
          C = rotate_left(B, 30);
          B = A;
          A = temp;
        }
        for (i = 60; i <= 79; i++) {
          temp = (rotate_left(A, 5) + (B ^ C ^ D) + E + W[i] + 0xCA62C1D6) & 0x0ffffffff;
          E = D;
          D = C;
          C = rotate_left(B, 30);
          B = A;
          A = temp;
        }
        H0 = (H0 + A) & 0x0ffffffff;
        H1 = (H1 + B) & 0x0ffffffff;
        H2 = (H2 + C) & 0x0ffffffff;
        H3 = (H3 + D) & 0x0ffffffff;
        H4 = (H4 + E) & 0x0ffffffff;
      }
      var temp = cvt_hex(H0) + cvt_hex(H1) + cvt_hex(H2) + cvt_hex(H3) + cvt_hex(H4);
      return temp.toLowerCase();

    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function Geeks(event) {
      debugger;
      var y = SHA1(event.target.value);
      var x = document.getElementById("myfield").value;
      document.getElementById("sudo").innerHTML =
        "Entered Text: " + y;
    }
  </script>

  <p id="sudo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below methods

```
<input id="mySelect" type="text" onchange="myFunction()">
```

or

```
<input id="mySelect" type="text" onkeypress="myFunction()">
```

i think `onKeypress` is the good option for your problem